# Ubuntu 22.04 nl80211 Not Found

Tags: wireless, kernel

I'm running 22.04 on an arm64 system. I've installed the kernel module for my PCIe WiFi card (88W9098 by NXP), and get the following issue when running:

Command: **sudo iw dev uap0 set 4addr on**

Response: **nl80211 not found.**

'uap0' supports 4addr mode, so it looks like I'm missing nl80211 kernel module. Is there a way to re-install it somehow?